# Formula for E(m) of the Atbash Cipher

Tags: encryption, affine-cipher

I'm studying mathematical cryptography and have been asked to find the encryption function for the Atbash cipher I know that it means a=z, b=y, c=x and so on but putting it into a formula has me a bit stuck. I already know affine ciphers version of the atbash is $ -(x+1) mod m $

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The math goes: add the integer assigned to `a`, the integer assigned to `z`, and from that constant (which can be pre-computed) subtract the integer assigned to the letter to encode; that gives the integer assigned to the encoded letter.

This works for `a` to `z` and encodings with consecurive letters of the alphabet assigned consecutive integer values (including ASCII; assigning 0 to `a` and 25 to `z`; assigning 1 to `a` and 26 to `z`). Usual associativity and commutativity rules for addition in $\mathbb Z$ are enough to prove that `a` is encoded to `z`, and vice versa. The rest follows by uh, intuition? Or induction if we really strive for rigor.

In C, that gives

```
char Atbash(char x) {
  return ('a'+'z')-x;
}
```